# How does Enumerator.new work with block passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I struggle a little bit with understanding how the `Enumerator.new` method works.
Assuming example from documentation:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

p fib.take(10) # => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Where's the loop break condition, how does it know how many times loop should to iterate (as it doesn't have any explicit break condition and looks like infinite loop) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerator` uses [Fibers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fiber.html) internally. Your example is equivalent to:

```
require 'fiber'

fiber = Fiber.new do
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    Fiber.yield a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

10.times.map { fiber.resume }
#=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** I think I understand your question now, I will still keep my original answer below.

`y << a` is an alias for `y.yield(a)`, which is basically a `sleep` with return value. Each time a value is requested from the enumerator with `next`, the execution is continued until another value is yielded.

---

Enumerators do not need to enumerate a finite number of elements, so they *are* infinite. For example, `fib.to_a` will never terminate, because it tries to build an array with an infinite number of elements.

As such, enumerators are great as a representation of infinite series such as the natural numbers, or in your case, the fibonacci numbers. The user of the enumerator can decide how many values it needs, so in your example `take(10)` determines the break condition if you will.

The break condition itself is in the implementation of `Enumerator#take`. For demonstration purposes, we can make our own implementation called `my_take`:

```
class Enumerator
  def my_take(n)
    result = []
    n.times do
      result << self.next
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Where you could of course "mentally substitute" your `n.times` loop with your classical C style  `for (i=0; i<n; i++)`. There's your break condition. `self.next` is the method to get the next value of the enumerator, which you can also use outside of the class:

```
fib.next
#=> 1
fib.next
#=> 1
fib.next
#=> 2
fib.next
#=> 3
```

That said, you can of course build an enumerator that enumerates a finite number of values, such as the natural numbers in a given range, but that's not the case here. Then, the Enumerator will raise a `StopIteration` error when you try to call `next`, but all values already have been enumerated. In that case, you have two break conditions, so to speak; the one that breaks earlier will then win. `take` actually handles that by rescuing from the error, so the following code is a bit closer to the real implementation (however, `take` is in fact implemented in C).

```
class Enumerator
  def my_take(n)
    result = []
    n.times do
      result << self.next
    end
    result
  rescue StopIteration
    # enumerator stopped early
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool, but where is any statement which breaks the loop ? `<<` ?

Comment: @LeszekAndrukanis see my edit. The enumerator is indeed infinite, there is no break condition in the enumerator. It's up to the consumer of the values to decide how many values he wants!

Comment: @p11y I think the OP wants to know how Ruby manages to stop the infinite loop after each iteration

Comment: @LeszekAndrukanis ok I think I got your question now, edited my answer again.